# Component returned by function is not working in Route component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have checked multiple answers, but didn't get the solution.

```
...
render(){
    const HomePage = () => {
        return(<Home />);
    }
    return(
        <Routes>
            {/* not working */}
            <Route path="/home" element={HomePage} />
            {/* working */}
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        </Routes>
    );
}
...
```

Aren't both the same thing here?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Change this

```
<Route path="/home" element={HomePage} />
```

To this

```
<Route path="/home" element={HomePage()} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: consider adding some documentation or explanation about  how your answer solves the problem